# On Moused Clicked event not triggered from JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Just trying to learn JavaFX and my goal of this is to have the splitpane divider move all the way to the right if the "Hide Terminal" button is clicked. Here is what I've set up in Scene Builder:
[image]

I tried adding code to the initialise() method and can confirm that runs.

Here is the code that's supposed to be triggered from the On Mouse Clicked event:

```
@FXML
void terminalHideShow(MouseEvent event) {
    terminalHideShowButton.rotateProperty().setValue(180.0);
    terminalCommandListOutput.getItems().add("TEXT"); // a test

    if(mainWindow.getDividerPositions()[0] > 0.99)
    {
        mainWindow.setDividerPositions(0.7);
        terminalHideShowLabel.setText("Hide Terminal");
    }
    else
    {
        mainWindow.setDividerPositions(1.0);
        terminalHideShowLabel.setText("Show Terminal");
    }
}
```

The FXML itself:

```
<Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Hide Terminal" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
   <graphic>
      <ImageView fx:id="terminalHideShowButton" accessibleRole="BUTTON" onMouseClicked="#terminalHideShow" rotate="180.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../images/angle-right-circle.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </graphic>
</Label>
```

Comment: Isn't your logic backwards? You have "if the divider position is more than 0.99, set it to 1" (which can never move it more than 0.01) and "else set it to 0.7".

Comment: @James_D good pickup, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that in order to be able to click the ImageView I had to set the Pick On Bounds options for it, as the transparency parts wasn't clickable, which was most of the arrow picture.

For whatever reason also, the ImageView is prevented from being clicked whilst wrapped by a label object. Moving the Label and ImageView to separate objects fixed the main issue, even though you can still set action handlers to them whilst "wrapped".

Answer (score 1):

For the if condition if you want to hide the divider, initial position of the divider should be greater than 0.99 and in your attached picture it seems that it's less than 0.99. So in this case you should change the if condition like this

```
if(mainWindow.getDividerPositions()[0] < 0.99)
{
     mainWindow.setDividerPositions(0.7);
     terminalHideShowLabel.setText("Hide Terminal");
}
```

I don't know what your desired criteria for hiding the divider ... so change your if and else statement like that way. I just mentioned the example in basis of you attached image